# How to allow text to wrap to a new line within a dynamically sized container?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, tsx

I'm working on a React application using Tailwind CSS, and I'm facing an issue with text overflow within a dynamically sized container. I have a component (CenteredRectangle.tsx) that is intended to display a centered rectangle with text content. I want the text to wrap to a new line when it reaches the end of the container, allowing both horizontal and vertical expansion based on the content.

However, the text is still overflowing outside the container, and I'd like it to wrap to a new line instead. How can I achieve this while maintaining a dynamically sized container?

[image: It's this way now]

[image: It should be like this]

Here's the current code for the component:

````
import React from 'react';

interface CenteredRectangleProps {
  text: string;
}

const CenteredRectangle: React.FC<CenteredRectangleProps> = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded-md text-black text-center max-w-screen-md w-full overflow-x">
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CenteredRectangle;```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the break-all class in the p tag.
Here is the sample code:

```
    import React from 'react';

interface CenteredRectangleProps {
  text: string;
}

const CenteredRectangle: React.FC<CenteredRectangleProps> = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded-md text-black text-center max-w-screen-md w-full overflow-x">
        <p className="break-all">{text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CenteredRectangle;
```

Comment: Very good answer the only thing is that you need to use break-words in stead of break all. Break all will cut a word in half. And based on example given words are intact.

Answer (score 2):

to allow text to wrap to a new line within a dynamically sized container, below are some modifications which you need to follow:

- Apply Tailwind CSS utility classes for dynamic sizing of your container. You can use **max-w-screen-md** for the maximum width and **h-full** for the maximum height
- Use Tailwind CSS utility classes to handle text overflow. You can use **overflow-auto** to enable scrolling if the content is too large, and **whitespace-normal** for text wrapping.

  ```
   import React from 'react';

    interface CenteredRectangleProps {
      text: string;
     }

   const CenteredRectangle: React.FC<CenteredRectangleProps> = ({ text }) 
   => {
  return (
   <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
     <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded-md text-black text-center max-w- 
      screen-md w-full overflow-auto">
      <p className="whitespace-normal">{text}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
   );
  };

   export default CenteredRectangle;
  ```
- replaced **overflow-x** with **overflow-auto** to allow vertical scrolling if the content overflows vertically
- added the **whitespace-normal** class to allow text wrapping